# Sortedlist/Dictionary modify a key's value at an index

Tags: c#, sortedlist

So what i want to do is this:

```
SortedList<char, int> list = new SortedList<char, int>()
 {
    {'a', 31312},
    {'b', 42224},
    {'c', 42342},
};

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
      dict.Values[i] = i;
}
```

But it is not possible, when i try it give

> This operation is not supported on SortedList nested types because
> they require modifying the original SortedList

It is just an example code, so i need a dictionary/sortedlist or somehwat suitable and later i want to modify the values at a specific index like what i did in the for.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `List<T>` and then `Sort()` it?

Comment: A dictionary you cannot change the key (only the value).  You can either deleted the object from the dictionary or add a new object to the dictionary.  The error indicates you are trying to change the key.

Comment: I want to change the value, maybe i'm doing wrong? @jdweng

Comment: You probably mean to iterate over the keys instead.

Comment: You want to add to dictionary : dict.Add(List[i].Value,List[i]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have defined `SortedList` named `list`, but then call `dict`
2. Index type is `char` and You are using `int` (`int i`)

You can change `SortedDictionary` values as shown below:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<char, int>()
{
    {'a', 31312},
    {'b', 42224},
    {'c', 42342},
};

for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'c'; ++c)
{
    dict[c] = (int)c;
}
```

Comment: dict - list my bad.

Comment: Okey this is not really what i wanted originally but i changed my project structure to be use that way so in the end it solved my problem, thanks :)